# Epsilon-N method: proving recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

How do you prove an iterative sequence like
$$x_{n+1} = ax_n + b$$
$$ 0< |a|< 1   $$
by using epsilon-N method?

I tried create a closed form of the sequence
$$a^{n+1}x_0 + b\sum_{i=0}^n a^i$$.

And then I set an inequality that
$$|a^{n+1}x_0 + b\sum_{i=0}^n a^i - b(1-a)^-1| < \epsilon $$
where
$$\epsilon > 0$$
$$n> N$$
Which is the lowerbound for n.

I don't know the next step of the proof. How can I rearrange the inequality so that only n stands on one side of the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I rearrange the inequality so that only $n$ stands on one side of the inequality?

Like this, maybe?
$$|a^{n+1}x_0 + b\sum_{i=0}^n a^i - b(1-a)^{-1}| < \epsilon$$
$$|a^{n+1}x_0 + b\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1} - b(1-a)^{-1}| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{a-1}\right|\cdot|a^{n+1}(a-1)x_0 + b(a^{n+1}-1) + b| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{a-1}\right|\cdot|a^{n+1}(a-1)x_0 + b\cdot a^{n+1}| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{(a-1)x_0+b}{a-1}\right|\cdot|a^{n+1}| < \epsilon$$
Now you can take $\log$ (unless $(a-1)x_0+b=0$, and be careful with signs, $|a|<1$) and separate $n$.